# Is it necessary to hash data POSTed if using SSL?

Tags: security, ssl, architecture, consistent-hashing

In some sensitive apps, like payment systems, code is set up as such: when user sends info to server, for example:

```
{money_amount: 5, receiver_id: 2}
```

It's also required to send over a hashed string, like:

```
hash_by_client = make_hash_from_string("money" + money_amount + "receiver" + receiver_id)
```

The purpose: so that when server receives the data, it independently, but using the same algorithm, computes another hashed string (`hash_by_sever`) , and compare `hash_by_sever` with `hash_by_client`. If they are equal, then server is sure the POSTed data is not modified, and can be trusted to proceed.

Question: if we are using SSL/TSL/https connections, is this setup still necessary?

Comment: This seems to be asking for opinion-based answers unless you can point to a specific standard.  The important thing is to assume that the sender is attempting to hack the server.  SQL injection, buffer overrun, crashing from invalid data, changing account or other IDs to steal data, etc..    A hash makes that harder because it's a cheap first check that the data makes sense.  It should not be the only check, because a hacked client can create bad data and a valid hash for it.  A nonce (one-time-token) also helps as being a cheap way to filter replay and denial of  service attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary. The information sent will already be encrypted, so adding a hash doesn't improve on that.

As mentioned in a comment a hash might be good to catch "if the sender is attempting to hack." True, but note that your hash_by_client() function is (most likely) executing in javascript which the potential hacker can easily access.

So the hash merely provides a false sense of security.